# How come IE8 does not allow a port number at the end of a URL?

Tags: windows, firefox, google-chrome, internet, internet-explorer

Typing "www.example.com" works fine in IE8, but when I enter "www.example.com:8000" it doesn't work (I know it works for some people).

Port 8000 is necessary because I do a lot of web development testing and I run web servers on that port.

The error I get reads:

```
The webpage cannot be displayed.
Most likely cause: Some content or files on this web page require a program that you don't have installed.
```

Of course, on the same Windows machine Chrome and Firefox both work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IE is finicky when it comes to adding port numbers - if you want to use them, you *MUST* add http:// at the front, so try http://www.example.com:port

Comment: This is actually fairly obvious: `www.example.com:8000` means using a protocol called `www.example.com` to resolve the identifier `8000`. URLs that lack a colon (and hence a protocol designator) are special-cased to use HTTP (or FTP, if the name begins with "ftp.".

Comment: It's IE being a bit pedantic - other browsers work out what you're trying to do without any fuss.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably some privacy or policy settings getting in the way.  Third party applications tend to ignore these settings, so only Microsoft's applications are usually implement them.

To update your Privacy settings:  Control Panel -> Internet Options -> "Security" and "Privacy" tabs (I'm not sure which options, but I suspect that these would be two good places to look)

To update your Policy settings:  Contact your local network administrator if you're in a corporate environment, or see the following web page for information on getting into the Local Policy Editor:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307882